# Waterfall | R | ggplot2 | Error Message

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, waterfall

I'm trying to plot a waterfall using sample code provided on the web.

I'm getting an error message after the data prep and when it's time to do the plotting.

```
# Create Plot
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(desc, fill = type)) + 
                    geom_rect(aes(x = desc,
                    xmin = id - 0.45, xmax = id + 0.45,
                    ymin = end, ymax = start))
# Error here.  "Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: X"
```

There's also part of the code that I don't understand what it's doing.

```
df <- df[,c(3,1,4,2)]
```

Complete R code available here:
https://gist.github.com/khaki22/fd33072e21dc3e2290b213c53366d2a2#file-r_waterfall_plot

Help! Please. :-)

Comment: `geom_rect()` doesn't take `x` as an argument within the `aes()` call.

Comment: `df[,c(3,1,4,2)]` means "take the 3rd, 1st, 4th, and 2nd columns of the data frame df, in that order".

Comment: Errors and warnings are different. Errors use the word "error", and stop the code from running at all. Warnings mean the code completed, but it seemed a little irregular. If you get a warning, but you also get a plot that looks good, then you can probably safely ignore it. In this case, you could probably delete the `x = desc` part and clear up the warning.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on the order of the data frame, Phil.

Comment: Gregor: When I remove x=desc, I get an error message and a blank, white plot.

> # Error here.  "Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: X"
> # Create Plot
> ggplot(df, aes(desc, fill = type)) + 
+                     geom_rect(aes(
+                     xmin = id - 0.45, xmax = id + 0.45,
+                     ymin = end, ymax = start))
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 6, 0

Comment: Try: `ggplot(df) + geom_rect(aes(xmin = id - 0.45, xmax = id + 0.45, + ymin = end, ymax = start, fill = type))`. In this case at least, you shouldn't take that blog very seriously.

Comment: Axeman:  When I do that, I get a new error message.  "Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 6, 0"